# Something which cannot be experienced

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single English word that conveys that idea that something cannot be experienced. Any ideas?

To be specific: at least one of the standard definitions of such a word would have the general meaning of  '(something) that cannot be experienced.'

Comment: if something is inexplicable, it cannot be described clearly in words

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of such things?

Comment: I would say *romance*, at least in my case. :'(

Answer (score 11):

In philosophy, if something is [**transcendent**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=transcendent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=nZ9hWdDLN4eBuASH1rQg), it's not realizable in human experience.

Comment: Please cite a source and give a link.  We like to see sources and links here.  When you do, ping me and I will upvote.

Comment: I am providing the hyperlink this time because your answer is *very correct!* @ab2 please excuse; Jason F will do it themselves next time.

Comment: Please edit your post to conform with [the network-wide guidelines of how to reference others’ work](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) which you've copypasta’d in here.

Answer (score 5):

Unknowable.

Note the word *experience* used in this definition by Merriam-Webster Dictionary:

> **unknowable** :  not knowable; especially :  lying beyond the limits of human experience or understanding

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unknowable

Answer (score 5):

Here are some others depending on your intent. I'm providing all of these because it was not clear from your question if you wanted something philosophical or concrete.

[unattainable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unattainable)

> not able to be reached or achieved.

[impossible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/impossible)

> not able to occur, exist, or be done.

[impracticable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/impracticable)

> impossible in practice to do or carry out.

Transcendent was already mentioned (a great option if the intent is to be philosophical or metaphorical)

[inimitable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/inimitable)

> so good or unusual as to be impossible to copy; unique.

[incomparable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/incomparable)

> without an equal in quality or extent; matchless.

[nonpareil](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nonpareil)

> having no match or equal; unrivaled.

[unparalleled](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unparalleled)

> having no parallel or equal; exceptional.

---

*Source Material for all entries: [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/)*

Comment: Please edit your post to conform with [the network-wide guidelines of how to reference others’ work](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) which you've copypasta’d in here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thx. Having a cow right now Mari, and a little bit of a fit :/ Sorry, no offense to you. You've been great. I'm just really considering leaving this site entirely. I have gotten mostly negative feedback from virtually all senior members except a handful such as yourself & some others. Frankly it looks like jealously of some sort. Every single answer I post has captious nonsense remarked on. And *everything* could be answered by a Google search. I mean come on. I learned everything I know reading 2000+ books. But if I Google or paste my knowledge for users bene Im copypasta'ing? Ugh.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And dang near every question, 85% of them or better, at least, should be closed, by those standards. Even the remaining valid ones can still be found by doing one's own research. Just ticks me off. What's good for the goose isn't good for the gander according to some. Sorry. Little upset.

Comment: Resist! EL&U needs more users like you. The hardcore members prefer longish answers that are personal. If for example you had chosen just two of those words and explained "why" the OP should consider them, that would have made your answer unique, and special. Users could say "Ahh... Kace36, inimitable as always" You need a sense of humor in this place, but usually the mods are friendly, and helpful, and they do listen.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, thanks. Just upset about some messages I received earlier this evening. No biggie I guess. Having trouble deciphering now what I should answer and shouldn't and it's made it difficult is all. Thank you though.

Comment: well, you could visit meta, you'd have a better idea what the habitat is like. You could even write a question asking about citations and quotations. Or you could visit the meta archives and do a bit of swotting, there aren't that many relevant posts concerning plagiarism etc. (This I would recommend)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Absolutely, will do. Thx again!

Comment: Well what happens is the diehard brigade tend to be the most vociferous and outspoken, but its dictated by a sense of pride because many feel this site is a bit special, and they want to keep standards high, or stop the low quality questions from swamping the site. How successful they are is disputable...